# Change background color using event handler

Tags: javascript, html, events, eventhandler

I'm trying to create a simple form where I have three divs stacked on top of one another. When each box is clicked, their colors need to change (one red, one green, and one blue). I need to do this using only one event handler. I am stuck on my code, I'm hoping one of you can guide me through this. I would really appreciate it! Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Color Changer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="squareOne" class="listener"></div>
    <div id="squareTwo" class="listener"></div>
    <div id="squareThree" class="listener"></div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('squareOne').onclick = changeColor;

function changeColor() {
    document.body.style.color = "red";
    return false;
}
```

CSS:

```
#squareOne {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareTwo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareThree {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use `addEventListener` to add the event to the element. This means you have access to `this` which refers to the element in question.

You only specified color, but I assumed you meant background color so I have adjusted the style accordingly.

```js
document.getElementById('squareOne').addEventListener('click', changeColor);

function changeColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}
```

```css
#squareOne {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareTwo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareThree {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
    <div id="squareOne" class="listener"></div>
    <div id="squareTwo" class="listener"></div>
    <div id="squareThree" class="listener"></div>
```

If you want to make this dynamic, you could add the color to the element as a data attribute and add the event listener to each element:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('listener');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
 elements[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor)  
}

function changeColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
}
```

```css
#squareOne {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareTwo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareThree {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
    <div id="squareOne" class="listener" data-color="red"></div>
    <div id="squareTwo" class="listener" data-color="green"></div>
    <div id="squareThree" class="listener" data-color="blue"></div>
```

Comment: Oh man that was so helpful, I really appreciate it! Sometimes I think too far into it and end up confusing myself.

Comment: No worries, You could use a separate function per `div` such as `changeToGreen` etc, this is a bit more scale-able though

Comment: You could also use forEach and querySelectorAll, that's just my preference:
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.listener');
boxes.forEach(function(box){
  box.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
})
function changeColor(e) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('color');
}

Comment: I saw that answer and was about to comment before you deleted it. There is no reason to use `querySelectorAll` when you know that you are searching for classes. You could use `foreach` to iterate over the array, but some older browsers don't like that. Looking at you IE8. Also, please refrain from adding that much code to comments. It is hard to read since it is unformatted. If you think it is a viable answer then submit it as such.

Comment: @Charlie_Nex don't forget to mark as the answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click',  changeColor);

function changeColor(e) {
    colors = {'squareOne': 'red', 'squareTwo': 'blue', 'squareThree': 'green'}
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    target.style.backgroundColor = colors[target.id];
    return false;
}
```

```css
#squareOne {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareTwo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#squareThree {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Color Changer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="squareOne" class="listener"></div>
    <div id="squareTwo" class="listener"></div>
    <div id="squareThree" class="listener"></div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or `e.srcElement` to support IE < 9

Comment: Close but not quite

Comment: @CarlMarkham Thanks for editing. That said, your `data` attribute approach is a more appropriate.

Comment: Mine is one possibility, yours is another. Good for the OP to see the options

Answer (score 0):

using Event Listner to change the background body color of the page

```js
const body = document.querySelector('#body')
const text = document.querySelector('#text')
const red =document.querySelector('#red')
const green =document.querySelector('#green')
const orange= document.querySelector('#orange')

function Red(red){
body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
text.innerHTML = 'color changed to red '
return red;
}

function Green(){
body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
text.innerHTML = 'color changed to green '

} 
function Orange(){
body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
text.innerHTML = 'color changed to orange '

}

red.addEventListener("click",Red);
green.addEventListener("click",Green);
orange.addEventListener("click",Orange);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body  id="body">
    <!-- Heading -->

<h1> i am heading</h1>

<button id="red">red</button>
<button id="green">green</button>
<button id="orange">orange</button>
<p id="text"></p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```